# Need to build automake for the host in buildroot

Tags: linux, buildroot, uclibc

I have just upgraded to latest version of buildroot. With the previous version after buildroot was done, I would see automake/autoconf in my uclibc/usr/bin. But with the latest version of buildroot ( 2014 ), I dont see that anymore.

Can anyone let me know how do I add packages which just to be built for the host? I.e I want to see host-package in the output/build folders

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, you should never use anything in output/build, this directory contains temporary build directories. If you want to use host utilities, you should run them from the place they are installed, i.e in output/host/usr/bin/.

Regarding specifically automake, there is no option in menuconfig to enable the build of its host variant, because it normally gets built as a dependency of another package. So, you have two solutions:

1/ Create a Buildroot package for what you're trying to build, and make it depend on host-automake. That's the best solution.

2/ Run "make host-automake". This will force the build of the host variant of automake.

Comment: Thanks, I think (1) would be the best approach for me.